# python - different array length along interpolation axis?

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, interpolation, odeint

I am trying to use the Python interpolation function to get the value y for a given x but I am getting the error "raise ValueError("x and y arrays must be equal in length along along interpolation axis" even though my arrays have both equal size and shape (according to what I get when I use .shape in my code). I am quite new to programming so I don't know how to check what else could be different in my arrays. Here is my code:

```
s = []

def slowroll(y, t):

    phi, dphi, a = y
    h = np.sqrt(1/3. * (1/2. * dphi**2 + 1/2.*phi**2))
    da = h*a
    ddphi = -3.*h*dphi - phi

    return [dphi,ddphi,da]


phi_ini = 18.
dphi_ini = -0.1
init_y = [phi_ini,dphi_ini,1.]
h_ini =np.sqrt(1/3. * (1/2. * dphi_ini**2. + 1/2.*phi_ini**2.))

t=np.linspace(0.,20.,100.)

from scipy.integrate import odeint

sol = odeint(slowroll, init_y, t)

phi = sol[:,0]
dphi = sol[:,1]
a=sol[:,2]
n=np.log(a)
h = np.sqrt(1/3. * (1/2. * dphi**2 + 1/2.*phi**2))

s.extend(a*h)
x = np.asarray(s)
y = np.asarray(t)
F = interp1d(y, x, kind='cubic') 

print F(7.34858263)
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding in the required imports, I've been unable to duplicate your error with version 2.7.12. What python version are you running?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

s = []

def slowroll(y, t):

    phi, dphi, a = y
    h = np.sqrt(1/3. * (1/2. * dphi**2 + 1/2.*phi**2))
    da = h*a
    ddphi = -3.*h*dphi - phi

    return [dphi,ddphi,da]


phi_ini = 18.
dphi_ini = -0.1
init_y = [phi_ini,dphi_ini,1.]
h_ini =np.sqrt(1/3. * (1/2. * dphi_ini**2. + 1/2.*phi_ini**2.))

t=np.linspace(0.,20.,100.)

from scipy.integrate import odeint

sol = odeint(slowroll, init_y, t)

phi = sol[:,0]
dphi = sol[:,1]
a=sol[:,2]
n=np.log(a)
h = np.sqrt(1/3. * (1/2. * dphi**2 + 1/2.*phi**2))

s.extend(a*h)
x = np.asarray(s)
y = np.asarray(t)
F = interp1d(y, x, kind='cubic') 

print F(7.34858263)
```

Output: 
`2.11688518961e+20`

Comment: Interesting.... I get no errors as well, but a slightly different output result `>>> 2.02845299116e+20`

Comment: Interesting indeed... My previous run was on my Windows machine running 2.7.12. If I run it on my Ubuntu 14.04 with python version 2.7.6 I get `>>>2.09312088926e+20`.  My scipy versions are 0.17.0 and 0.13.3, respectively.  Must have to do with slight variations in the actual interpolation function

Comment: Thank you both! I had the second to last line in different place in my actual project and when I heard that it works for you I changed it to the above and it now works! But I realised that the above code gives me x when I give it y but I want the reverse. When I reverse y and x in the code above, I get another error "numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: singular matrix".  Any ideas about this?